# searching all tk websites using google search gadget maybe

Tags: javascript, web-applications, blogs

I want to search for all TK domains or websites on with the .TK domain extension but the only thing I could find was this blog:

[Search all Dot TK websites](http://searchtksites.blogspot.com).

I am not able to understand how it works, and there is one problem with it that is it only displays 10 pages of results out of 50,000 results.

But if someone knows any alternative, or how can I can make a blog like this that would be great.

I searched online a lot but can't find anything related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for all .TK domains, search for `site:*.tk`.

**[Example](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A%2a.tk)**

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't show all of domains, and it also doesn't show expired ones, which are actually ones am after.

Comment: @tereško Well, I don't really know any other way, unless you were to sort through the results by hand.